# how to debug VSCode custom language extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, language-server-protocol

I want to test my VSCode custom language extension, which introduces a new language and is implemented through Language Server Protocol.

Although my language server itself is tested workable, when binding to the VSCode client, the client just CANNOT show the expected result. For example, after I trigger a "textDocument/definition" request from the client by left click the variable name, the client just hold and displays the "in-progress" progress bar. However, the language server log shows that the request is send and the correct response is send back successfully...

How can I find the reason why the result is not displayed?

---

What I've tried:

- debug the extension by pressing "F5", but the client source code is written in TypeScript and is complicated. I can't find the reason yet.